# What information should be turned into theory?

Tags: logic, epistemology, philosophy-of-science, reason, theory

I want to have a theory-based approach to knowledge.

I know that all a priori judgments alone should not be turned into theories since their truth is independent of experience and empirical evidence, so we have a posteriori judgment left, but the problem is that it is not psychologically possible to turn all posteriori judgments into theories, so then

Which information should be turned into theories while taking into account what is psychologically possible?

Comment: Yeah, Kant wouldn't agree that a priori judgments can't be part of a theory, rather that a theory may involve both logic and experience o

Comment: Thus a hypothesis may have a necessary component and a contingent component.  Science, theory-based knowledge, would be impossible without the a priori.  The premise, that theory contains nothing a priori, begs question.  Question in danger of being closed due to lack of clarity, and this may have something to do with it.  Maybe a new question?  What is the role of a priori statements, e.g., math, in the formation of scientific theory?

Comment: @Gerry I said that a priori judgment alone should not be turned into a theory not that it can be a part of a theory and I don't care what Kant would think.

Answer (score 1):

Naturally emergent reproducible patterned behaviour.

Because it has utility.  Predictive potential.

If there is no pattern, there is little information to be analyzed.  Being non-patterned is not the same as having unfound patterns.  But without patterns... what is there to analyze?

So... recurring or reproducible patterned natural emergent behaviours.  That is where there is fruit to be squeezed and juice to be made.

Comment: Right, we want to know about things so that we can take advantage of them.